# A cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A cycle is a simple path of length at least $1$ which begins and ends at the same vertex.

In an undirected graph, a cycle must be of length at least $3$.

Could you explain me why that stands??

Comment: You must be considering undirected simple graphs: Undirected graphs with no (self) loops or parallel edges.

Answer (score 4):

In an undirected *simple* graph, there are no self loops (which are cycles of length 1) or parallel edges (which are cycles of length 2). Thus all cycles must be of length at least 3.

Comment: And a simple path can't use the same edge twice, so $A$-to-$B$-to-$A$ doesn't count as a cycle of length 2.

Comment: A path is simple if all edges and all vertices on the path, except possibly the first and last vertices, are distinct, right?? Could you explain me further why in an undirected simple graph there is no self loops or parallel edges??

Comment: @MaryStar That is what "simple graph" _means_. Most people assume that when you say "graph" you really mean "simple graph". If parallel edges and self-loops are allowed, it would be called a "multigraph" instead.